# Compare an angle of arcs with common point

Tags: math, geolocation, geometry, gps

Suppose, we have two pairs of plane coordinates with one common pair, so we got two segments with one common point.
We can calculate tangent for each segment to compare similarity of their angle (how small the delta of tangents).

When we turn to spheroid, and got two pairs of (lat, lon) GPS coordinates, also with one common point, 
and we got arcs instead of plain segments,

What equivalent measure should i use to check angle similarity, and how can i calculate it?

I need to know how "near" is one arc to another (or how small is the angle they make, because they have a common point)

Comment: I find your problem description a bit confusing.  Do you mean that you have two sides of a triangle (a plane triangle in one case, a spherical triangle in the other) and you want to calculate the interior angle at the common vertex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer is related to [Great-circle_navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation)

The equivalent of plane tangent is a tangent of angle (π/2 - α0) in figures 1 and 2, i.e. an angle between an arc and equator. The difference between two tangents of two arcs will show how  "near" is one arc to another

Answer (score 0):

Convert (lat,lon) to (x,y,z).

Each pair of points forms a triangle with the center of the sphere, and the plane that contains the triangle contains the arc between the points.  Use the cross product between vectors from the center and fix the length to calculate the unit normal vector to each plane.

The angle between the normal vectors is the angle at which the arcs meet on the surface.  Use the dot product between the two vectors to get the cosine of this angle.